# Edit setup to allow argument mismatch in gcc compilation

Tags: python, numpy, gcc, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to install [this python package](https://pypi.org/project/orthpol-light/). Unfortunately, I am running into compilation errors due to rank mismatch.

A bug for this package has already been reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyorthpol/+bug/1890463). The bug report says that "The most pragmatic solution seems to be adding the compiler flag -fallow-argument-mismatch to the setup scripts."

I do not understand how to go about doing this. The setup.py script only contains this:

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension
import os
import glob
    
ext_modules = [ Extension('orthpol_light',
                      glob.glob(os.path.join('src','*.f'))) ]

setup(
    name='orthpol_light',
    version = "1.0.1",
    license = "COPYING.LESSER",
    description = "Light python wrapper for the ORTHPOL package",
    long_description=open("README.rst").read(),
    url="http://www.limitcycle.it",
    author = "Daniele Bigoni",
    author_email = "dabi@limitcycle.it",
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

Do I put the flag here? I really have no idea. The file that's causing the error is in src/r1mach.f

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is already implemented in the  software you link, in the `adapt-to-gcc10` branch [https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~catastropeia/pyorthpol/adapt-to-gcc10/revision/68](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Ecatastropeia/pyorthpol/adapt-to-gcc10/revision/68)

The relevant command then becomes

```
ext_modules = [ Extension('orthpol_light',
                          glob.glob(os.path.join('src','*.f')),
                          extra_f77_compile_args=['-fallow-argument-mismatch']) ]
```

Comment: BTW, I really wonder why that cannot just pass `SMALL(1)`, `LARGE(1)` in the Cray T3 branch. Not speaking about the availability of epsilon, nearest, spacing,.. in Fortran 90.

Comment: Woops, didn't see that commit. I'm really new to this too. Thanks for pointing this out!!!