# Installation failing for R package using Fortran

Tags: r, fortran

Trying to install DICE4 (https://github.com/predsci/DICE4) in console from Rstudio but unable to do so.

operating system: windows10
tried install DICE4 (https://github.com/predsci/DICE4) in console from Rstudio:

```
install_git(url="https://github.com/predsci/DICE4", subdir="dice")

Downloading git repo https://github.com/predsci/DICE4
"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe" clone --depth 1 --no-hardlinks https://github.com/predsci/DICE4 C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMppsYi\file16c54627620b0
-- R CMD build -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
v  checking for file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMppsYi\file16c54627620b0\dice/DESCRIPTION' (419ms)
-  preparing 'DICE': (1.4s)
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (938ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'DICE_4.0.tar.gz'
   
* installing *source* package 'DICE' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
using Fortran compiler: 'GNU Fortran (GCC) 12.2.0'
gfortran      -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c bnldev.f -o bnldev.o
gfortran      -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c epimulti.f -o epimulti.o
epimulti.f:404:37:

  403 |             call dblepr('curLLK1D',-1,curLLK1D,1)
      |                                      2
  404 |             call dblepr('accept%',-1,tmp,m)
      |                                     1
Error: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (scalar and rank-1)
epimulti.f:413:36:

  403 |             call dblepr('curLLK1D',-1,curLLK1D,1)
      |                                      2
......
  413 |       call dblepr('acceptence %',-1,accept_rate,nblock)
      |                                    1
Error: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (scalar and rank-1)
make: *** [C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-43~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:289: epimulti.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'DICE'
* removing 'C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.3.1/library/DICE'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Local/Temp/RtmpMppsYi/file16c545236314/DICE_4.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I assume you've already checked that Rtools is correctly installed and updated, but if not reinstalling the appropriate version for your R install version might help: https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/installing-rtools-for-compiled-code-via-rcpp/

Comment: Are you asking how to fix the broken Fortran code, or how to compile the broken Fortran code? If the latter, then you'll likely need to provide the compiler option `-fallow-argument-mismatch`, as seen in a [Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68730251/3157076). Or you can use GCC<10 which isn't fussy about this style of broken Fortran.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest R version (R 4.3.1). Had a similar issue the other day, updating R fixed it for me.

Comment: @francescalus, Thank you! In which file do I add the compiler option within the DICE4/src? https://github.com/predsci/DICE4

Comment: @Till Thank you! yes I am already using the latest R

Comment: @divibisan. Yes I just installed Rtool, thanks for the note!